# Cannot insert data into mySQL database: the INSERT query looks ok and the error logs won't show a thing

Tags: php, mysqli

I've got a mySQL error

> "Warning: mysqli_affected_rows() expects
>   parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in
>   /home/public_html/registroUsuario.php on line 22 Error Occurred 0 "

The file with the error takes information from an html form and inserts into a database. The file inserts the database credentials, so, the connection uses constants instead of the real values.

### HTML FORM

```
<form name="inscripcionForm" method="POST" action ="registroUsuario.php">
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
<input type="apellido" class="form-control" name="apellido" id="apellido">
<input type="nombres" class="form-control" name="nombres" id="nombres">
<input type="dni" class="form-control" name="dni" id="dni">
<input type="pass" class="form-control" name="pass" id="pass">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Inscribirme al Curso</button>
</form>
```

### PHP PROCESSING OF THAT FORM (registroUsuario.php)

```
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$apellido = strip_tags(strtoupper($_POST['apellido']));
$nombres = strip_tags(ucfirst($_POST['nombres']));
$dni = strip_tags($_POST['dni']);
$pass = strip_tags($_POST['pass']);

$conectar = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DATABASE)
OR die('Oops! Error '.mysqli_connect_errno());

$query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (userID, userEmail, userApellido, userNombres, userDNI, userPass) VALUES ('', '$email', '$apellido', '$nombres', '$dni', '$pass')";
    $insertarBase = mysqli_query($conectar,$query);

    $affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($insertarBase);
        if($affected_rows == 1){
            echo 'New User!';
            mysqli_close($conectar);
        } else {
            echo 'Error Occurred '.mysqli_connect_errno();
            mysqli_close($conectar);
        }
```

My Error Log doesn't show anything, even if I do have `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` at the top of the file.

What should I do? Is the query wrongly constructed? Thanks!

Comment: print the query before hitting the database and add it to the answer !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message states, `mysqli_affected_rows` expects a `mysqli` object as the parameter, while you're passing in a boolean.

Instead of

```
$affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($insertarBase);
```

it should be

```
$affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($conectar);
```